# Can't install git, and any program on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: software-installation

```
osman@thisisakella:~$ sudo apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (> 1:2.17.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (< 1:2.17.0-.) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-driver-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 (= 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: So what happens with `sudo apt --fix-broken install`?

Comment: @DKBose Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @OsmanNamso not the summary - we need to see the ENTIRE output - the imporatant stuff is wht you left out. Do not put output in comments - edit the output into your question, and format it properly so we can read it.

Answer (score 0):

try this first

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Comment: This won't work due to the OP's `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`